# MongoDB - handle non-existent arrays in $in query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
db.getCollection('authors').aggregate([
  { $match: {} }, 
  { $sort: { name: -1 } }, 
  { $addFields: { x_id___as___string: { $toString: "$_id" } } }, 
  { $lookup: {
      from: "books",
      let: { fkField:"$x_id___as___string" },
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$$fkField", "$authorIds"] } } }],
      as: "books"
    } 
  }
])
```

which works fine, **unless** the `authorIds` array is missing from some of the joined documents, in which case I get the error of

> "errmsg" : "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing",
>       "code" : 40081,
>       "codeName" : "Location40081"
>   } : aggregate failed

I've confirmed that manually adding `authorIds` as an empty array to the documents missing it fixes the query. My question is:

**How can I adjust this query to work with a non-existent `authorIds` field?**

Should I change my `$expr` to be an `$and` query, with the first value a check for array existence? Does Mongo **guarantee** short-circuiting? Is there a simpler check I can just add to the `$in` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add $cond in lookup pipeline $expr

```
db.getCollection('authors').aggregate([
  { $match: {} }, 
  { $sort: { name: -1 } }, 
  { $addFields: { x_id___as___string: { $toString: "$_id" } } }, 
  { $lookup: {
      from: "books",
      let: { fkField:"$x_id___as___string" },
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$$fkField", {$cond: {if: {$gt: ["$authorIds", null]}, then: "$authorIds", else: []}}] } } }],
      as: "books"
    } 
  }
])
```

that will check if `authorIds` exists. To make sure it's an actual array, you can use `$isArray`

```
db.getCollection('authors').aggregate([
  { $match: {} }, 
  { $sort: { name: -1 } }, 
  { $addFields: { x_id___as___string: { $toString: "$_id" } } }, 
  { $lookup: {
      from: "books",
      let: { fkField:"$x_id___as___string" },
      pipeline: [{ 
        $match: { 
          $expr: { 
            $in: [
              "$$fkField", 
              { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$authorIds" }, then: "$authorIds", else: [] } }
            ] 
          } 
        } 
      }],
      as: "books"
    } 
  }
])
```

Comment: Yeah! But wouldn't `isArray` be better, ie `{ $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$authorIds" }, then: "$authorIds", else: [] } }`? Would you be ok with me editing that into your answer?

Comment: I added it in as a second example - hope you don't mind. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Why is the `{ $match: {} },` stage required in the pipeline?

Comment: @prasad_ it's not doing anything in this particular example, you're right